# Building a valid SQL Query with optional parameters for search function

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, search

I have a search function de build.
We are using pure ASP.NET w\ VB.NET

We have multiple DropDownLists and we're building a search query with whatever was selected in those DDLs. My question is, how can I handle the blank values (unselected dropdownlist values) with the SQL Query ? I'm using AND operators in the query so if anything is blank it'll fail the search. If the dropdownlist has no selected value, i don't want the value to be part of the search. It would be easy to code with just 2-3 parameters, but we're looking thru at least 10 items and doing a SWITCH CASE or multiple IFs would soon become mayhem.

I'm sure there's an easier solution out there.

Thanks for the help
Have a nice day folks.

Comment: Are you building the SQL WHERE clause dynamically in a string in VB.NET or are you passing parameters to a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could default the parameters to NULL in the sproc and do something like

```
...
Where 
(someField1 = @Param1 OR @Param1 IS NULL) AND
(someField2 = @Param2 OR @Param2 IS NULL) AND
(someField3 = @Param3 OR @Param3 IS NULL) ....
```

etc

That way, if you pass NULL, that particular check will be true.